# Pathfinder: accessing Admin models from Frontend

Tags: atk4

In my application (residing in a subdirectory of webroot) I have an Admin area with models for category type lookups. In the main frontend application I have other models with references to the lookups defined in Admin.
Eg. Model Expense is defined in the Frontend, it has a reference to Model ExpenseType (which is a subclass of Model Lookup defined in Admin/lib/Model:

```
webroot
    My atk4 project
     -admin
        -lib
           -Model
              -Model_Lookup with subclass ExpenseType
     -atk4
     -atk4-addons
     ..
     -lib
        -Model
           -Model_Expense with reference to model ExpenseType
     ...
```

When opening the expenses page using CRUD -> setModel('Expense') I get a "fatal Error" - Model_ExpenseType cannot be found. So from what I understand (just starting with atk4) I need to addLocation to Pathfinder but I don't know how to do it so that Frontend models can access Admin models.

Comment: Not solved the issue but implemented a working solution: moved all models from admin/lib/Model to lib/Model. Expenses page still could not find Model_ExpenseType which is a subclass of Model_Lookup. When I replaced Model_ExpenseType with Model_Lookup for the Expense reference all worked fine. So I moved Model_ExpenseType into a separate file so now I'm still not sure which is the best approach but everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->pathfinder->addLocation('admin',array(
    'php'=>'lib'
));
```

inside your Api::init()

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out I wasn't far off - I had $this->addLocation instead of $this->pathfinder->addLocation. One thing remains a bit foggy - model Expense defined in Frontend only finds ExpenseType (subclass of Lookup defined in Admin) when it is in a separate file whereas model Material (defined in Admin) finds model MaterialType (another subclass of Lookup) defined in Lookup.php, regardless whether the Lookup models are in Admin or Frontend. What is the way to go? should I always place Model subclasses in their own file) Thanks.

Comment: preferably each class should be in it's respective file. also try renaming the file and examining the error output, it will tell you which locations are being searched, possibly the location sequence is different and it may result in different files being found first.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do like this:

```
given: webroot/lib/Model

cd webroot/admin/lib
ln -s ../../lib/Model .
```